AzurePowerShell@5 is failing to find parameter FederatedToken
I'm using the - task: AzurePowerShell@5 in an Azure DevOps pipeline using Azure PowerShell version 2.6.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines
The azureSubscription is set to an Azure DevOps service connection authenticating using a federated credential.
The AzurePowerShell@5 task fails when it runs Connect-AzAccount to authenticate.
Connect-AzAccount fails with the following error:

A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FederatedToken'.

FederatedToken should be a supported parameter based off this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-11.6.0
A more verbose log:
##[debug]Connect-AzAccount: D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\5.239.9\ps_modules\VstsAzureHelpers_\InitializeAzModuleFunctions.ps1:438
##[debug]Line |
##[debug] 438 |              & $command @args
##[debug]     |                         ~~~~~
##[debug]     | A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FederatedToken'.

It could be the case that the PowerShell version 2.6.0 doesn't support FederatedToken as a parameter but I don't see any documentation indicating that information.

Please share your actual PowerShell code being run with us rather than just the name of the .ps1 file being run. We need to see all the parameters you are passing to Connect-AzAccount.

Connect-AzAccount is being called by the task not me. So the .ps1 file should be a reference to the external task's code not mine.

I can reproduce the issue when the version of azurePowerShellVersion is 2.6.0, which has been out of support since at least 2020. According to the official documentation for the Azure PowerShell Support Lifecycle,

The Az PowerShell modules support lifecycle falls under the Azure SDK lifecycle policy. We support the last two minor versions of the current major version and last minor version of the previous major version of the Az PowerShell module.

Currently, the default version of the Az PowerShell module on Windows and Ubuntu images is 11.3.1. (See the default software on MS-hosted agent here). Testing with 11.3.1, it works fine.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.AzureSubscription }}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Save-AzContext -Path <pathname>'
    FailOnStandardError: true
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    pwsh: true


So far, the latest version of Azure PowerShell is 11.6.0. You can use it in the pipeline via preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.6.0'.

Thanks, this answers my question. I suspected it may have been due to the version, however I couldn't find confirmation in the documents I was looking at. Out of curiosity, where are you seeing that 2.6.0 has been out of support since 2020?

The document does not clearly state the specific days when a certain version will not be supported. The az 3.1.0 was published on 11/26/2019. According to "The Az PowerShell modules support lifecycle falls under the Azure SDK lifecycle policy. We support the last two minor versions of the current major version and last minor version of the previous major version of the Az PowerShell module", at that time, az 2.6.0 was already out of support.  You can also see Azure PowerShell release notes.
